# Install packages from a list through ansible

Tags: linux, bash, ansible

I have 2 servers named testserver and vsphere server. Ansible is installed on testserver and I have a list of packages stored in a text file packages.txt. How can I install those packages on vsphere server through ansible? This is my packages.txt file. I just have to fetch the package name from the packages.txt

```
hyperv-daemons| x86_64
hypervkvpd |x86_64
hyperv-tool | x86_64
nginx | x84_64
```

And this the yml file inside testserver

```
- hosts: vsphere
  tasks:
    - name: Install the packages
      shell: sh /root/test.sh
```

Test.sh contains

```
#/bin/bash
for i in `cat /root/packages`
do
echo $i
yum install $i
done
```

When I run this ansible script, I am getting an error: no packages.txt is found on vsphere. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would suggest that you use the [yum module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/yum_module.html) to install the packages. We can pass a list of packages to install by reading the `packages.txt` file. Seems this file is on the Ansible machine, so we can use `lookup` to get file contents.

Example:

```yaml
    # Run the awk command to get only package names
    - command: awk '{print $1}' path/to/packages.txt
      register: _pkgs
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
    
    - name: install packages
      yum:
        - name: "{{ _pkgs.stdout_lines }}"
          state: present
```

*Edit*

If you have  `| x86_64` in the file for every package, it wouldn't work with your shell script either. The easiest way would be get the clean list of packages with `awk` (above example updated), and use it for package install.

Comment: Worked like charm!

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it before @seshadri_c , can you please check the edited packages.txt file? Apparently that file will look like that. What changes should we make for it to get working?

Comment: how can I ignore " | x86_64 " part in the packages.txt file?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. I've updated the answer with the easier option.

Comment: or we can use command:  cut -d " " -f 1 right?

Comment: Yes you could, or even `awk '{print $1}' packages.txt`, but you'll have to output this to another file and use that file for `set_fact`.

Comment: Tried sed, getting an error:-- FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["sed", "-i", "s/ | x86_64//", "/root/packages"], "delta": "0:00:00.002620", "end": "2022-04-19 19:59:19.152827", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2022-04-19 19:59:19.150207", "stderr": "sed: can't read /root/packages: No such file or directory"

Comment: I forgot to use `delegate_to` option since the file is on the controller. I've updated the answer.

Comment: That resolved! Thanks alot Sesh!

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop instead
Just add to the role:

```
    - name: PREREQUISITES INSTALL install-linux | Install rpm software Linux
  yum:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: installed
  loop:
    - "{{ software_packages }}"
```

And to the defaults vars directory:

```
software_packages:
          packages:
            - package: "hyperv-daemons"
            - package: "hypervkvpd"
            - package: "hyperv-tool"
```

Comment: But that will include x86_64 along with the package name right? I just need the package name

Comment: I excluded it thinking that it would not be necessary.

For in the package line the exact name of what you need and it will work

for example:

`- package: "hyperv-daemons| x86_64"`

Comment: Cannot do that as the package.txt exists like that.

Comment: is necessary to run the ansible with txt? with vars would be easier to perform it.

Comment: We have 800+ packages in that list

Comment: Any method would be fine. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is to open the txt in notepad++ and edit all the lines toguether with center click, if every package has a single line, it will be the easiest method.

Comment: I guess, the answer from Sesadhri solved the issue! Thanks again for the help!